# Importance of center of mass for ceiling fan

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

I am learning about center of mass these days. While doing so, I encountered the equation

$$\sum {F_{external}} = ma_{com}$$

Then, it was written that with the help of this equation, it can be clearly seen that if the blades of ceiling fan are not kept at 120° the center of mass won't be at the center of the fan and the fan would start moving in a conical pendulum.

I am not getting why it will move in a conical pendulum?

I tried browsing the net but couldn't find answer. So I request you to please give me a hint, so that I can understand why the fan will move in a conical pendum.

Comment: I guess its just a fancy way to say that the centre of mass of the blades move in a circle

Comment: So, do you want to say that there is no effect even if the center of mass of fans is not at the center?

Comment: Of course there is. Since your cm is moving in a circle there needs to be a force acting on it, which the downrod provides

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Comment: @Luo Zenyan I think what you want to say is that as the distance of the blades' centre of mass from the downrod increases, so does the centripetal force that the downrod has to exert. Hence it takes the minimum force when the centre of mass roughly coincides with the downrod. However, I still don't understand how the former scenario would lead to motion in a conical pendulum. Does this have something to do with the downrod not being able to exert enough centripetal force on the centre of mass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession). It is a process called *precession which is a change in the orientation of the rotational axis of a rotating body ... other words, if the axis of rotation of a body is itself rotating about a second axis, that body is said to be precessing about the second axis*.

Because the blades are not arranged symmetrically, this results in an unbalanced net torque while the fan is rotating.